# Ionic Capacitor Barcode Scanner

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, ionic4, barcode-scanner, capacitor

I'm building android app using ionic4 and capacitor. I intent to use phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner in my app. But after installing that plugins, I began to fail building my apk. The hint I get from my Android Studio IDE is, that my app gradle using 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0', and the cordova gradle using "com.android.support:support-v4:27.+". I've tried to edit the cordova gradle to v4:28.0.0 (In Android Studio IDE), but still not working. What should I do?

My stack is:
node.js 6.4.1
ionic 4.12.0
angular 7.3.9
capacitor 1.0

and plugins phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner ^8.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Could you show us the **build.gradle files entirely**?

I installed the plug-in on my project with Capacitor, and there was no problem.
Remove the plug-in, and do these steps :

- `npm install phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner`
- `npm install @ionic-native/barcode-scanner`
- `ionic cap sync`

from https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner

I was dealing with issues using android and not androidX, so I did then :

`Refactor` --> `Migrate to AndroidX` --> `No Backup` --> `Do Refactor`

Then do  `Build` --> `Rebuild Project`

This worked for me

Comment: Hei man, thanks for your help, but I just kinda solve this problem yesterday (accidentally). All I did is just:

- Delete android and www folder from my project
- Run ng build and ionic capacitor run android
- And after the Android Studio opened, I just build the apk, and it works

I don't know how but, I guess it just want a (completely) new build from my project for it to run. Although, I did notice that the gradle difference version is still there but the apk is just built successfully. Anyway, thanks again for your help man.

Comment: Yes, it's quite a good solution. You should avoid modifying Android files except if you have errors from specific plugins, it is generated automatically, and it can quickly become a mess. You're welcome :)